# Hide row based on two conditions

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Worked on this for an hour using forums with no luck.

1. Want to use this code on any named sheet/workbook
2. All workbooks are setup the same
3. Want to look at column A and see if there is a value of "A" and look at Column P to see if there is a number zero
4. Hide that row if both are true
5. Run the entire sheet --- these sheets are always less than 500 rows.

Example Sheet:

[image: Example Sheet]

Comment: Hi there! We're not a script-writing service, but can/help with specifics.  So please share your research, and point out exactly where you're getting stuck implementing what you want. What have you attempted already? What were the results?

Comment: Add a calculated column Q = Ax&Px, and filter for Q="A0".
You can turn on Auto Filter for that range, and just select A0 for that column

Answer (score 1):

Create a helper column starting in S9 with the formula:

```
=IF((A9="A")*(P9=0)=1,"HIDE","SHOW")
```

In VBA use the following script:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Worksheet_Activate()

    'hide all lines that match criteria
    Dim i As Long

    'finds lines. 19 denotes the S column. Change 500 to last row.
    For i = 9 To 500
        If Cells(i, 19).Value = "HIDE" Then
            'hides row
            Rows(i).EntireRow.Hidden = True
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Every time the sheet is activated this code will run, and all rows that match the criteria will be hidden. You probably don't want this behavior, but this should get you pointed in the right direction.